# MGWT Scrolling Bug on iPhone iOS7 Cannot reach Bottom of scrollable Content

Tags: java, javascript, ios, gwt, mgwt

I use GWT 2.5.1 and the MGWT 1.2-Snapshot on a mobile web app on iOS7.

The problem is that when I scroll down I cannot reach the bottom of the content because it is hidden by the iOS7 Safari bottom status line. I see it working in the showcase example for MGWT, but could not figure out my problem.

Here is what I use in UiBinder:

```
<mgwt:LayoutPanel>  
<mgwt:ScrollPanel scrollingEnabledX="false" scrollingEnabledY="true">
<mgwt:RoundPanel>
    <g:HTMLPanel>
    very long text
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</mgwt:RoundPanel>
</mgwt:ScrollPanel>
</mgwt:LayoutPanel>
```

As you can see in the following screenshot you cannot see the bottom of the content. The scroll bar position indicator is also not visible anymore at some position.

[image]

[image]
**How can I fix that?**

These are my settings:

```
    ViewPort viewPort = new MGWTSettings.ViewPort();
    viewPort.setTargetDensity(DENSITY.MEDIUM);
    viewPort.setUserScaleAble(false).setMinimumScale(1.0).setMinimumScale(1.0).setMaximumScale(1.0);
    viewPort.setHeightToDeviceHeight().setWidthToDeviceWidth();
    MGWTSettings settings = new MGWTSettings();
    settings.setViewPort(viewPort);
    settings.setIconUrl("apple-touch-icon.png");
    settings.setAddGlosToIcon(true);
    settings.setFullscreen(true);
    settings.setPreventScrolling(true);
    MGWT.applySettings(settings);
```

It seems to work if I do not use this:

```
viewPort.setHeightToDeviceHeight().setWidthToDeviceWidth();
```

Comment: Got the same problem. Posted on mgwt google group: 

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mgwt/EZvI6ee6LyI

Please update if any luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. Do not use this line:

```
viewPort.setHeightToDeviceHeight().setWidthToDeviceWidth();
```

And always refresh a ScrollPanel if the content changes.